# Parametrization line integral in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: calculus

So i have to calculate line integral with function $$\\f(x,y,z) = xz$$

where the curve is described as
$$\\x=y^2, x=z, y \in[-1,1]$$

I've came up with parametrization
$$\\x=t^2\\y=t\\z=t^2\\t\in[-1,1]$$

So my integral would be
$$\\\oint t^4
\sqrt{4t^2+1+4t^2} \ dt$$

Is it the right approach?

Comment: Yeah it's fine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Notice as well that
\begin{align*}
4t^{2} + 1 + 4t^{4} = (2t^{2} + 1)^{2}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i think i can take it from this point. The biggest issue i had was that parametrization, because if i understood correctly, i have to calculate the curve that given by $\\y=x^2$ from point (1,1,1) through (0,0,0) to (1,-1,1)? Is my thinking clear here as well?